# Adding a letter to the side in chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

As you can see in the below MWE, at the bottom of the molecule, a bond can be seen coming out of a hydrogen (H) atom where it should be coming out of the nitrogen atom (N). I was looking for a command along the lines of `\chemleft` (similar to `\chemabove` or `\chembelow`) to put the H on the left of the N while still having the bond come out of the N with no success. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\chemfig{-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30](=[-90]O)-[:30]\chemabove{N}{H}-[:-30](-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH)-[:-90]-[:-150]-[:-90]-[:-150]HN-[:-90](-[:-150]H_2N)=[:-30]NH}

\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: @Eridan, it is in section II.5 of the manual (v. 1.2d for me)

Comment: @DRi Ah, I completely missed that when I went through the manual the first time. Thank you.

Comment: @ Eridan, Thank clemens, I had forgotten these options too but found them back in the manual when he mentioned them and gave the simple and smart solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial part of the molecule is

```
-[:-150]HN-[:-90]
```

where the first bond ends at the `N` and the second starts at the `H`. Exactly for cases like this there are the parameters three and four of the bonds:

```
<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,arrival>,<tikz>]
```

They are described in section 5 *Departure and arrival atoms* of part II in the `chemfig` manual (v1.2d). `<departure>` and `<arrival>` are integer numbers referring to the corresponding atoms of the group of atoms where the bond starts (`<departure>`) or where the bond ends (`<arrival>`). In this case 1 would refer to the `H` and 2 would refer to the `N`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{-[:-150]HN-[:-90]}
\chemfig{-[:-150]HN-[:-90,,2]}
\chemfig{-[:-150,,,2]HN-[:-90,,2]}% just to be *really* safe

\end{document}
```

[image]